# What is Grantee Me in the context of AWS S3 ACL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The S3 ACL Grantee is a very mysterious thing, not well documented (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html), super confusing.

One point is clear for me, sometimes it shows the aws nickname, instead of the canonical ID.

Sometimes there is Grantee ME, standing in the dropdown list of grantee.

Have no idea what that is ?